# Is there mapM/mapM_ in core.async?

Tags: clojure, monads, core.async

I am looking for a function in core.async that does the following:

```
(map-m #(go (inc %)) (range 5))
; => a channel with one value inside: '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

A simple (non-lazy) implementation:

```
; mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
(defn map-m [f col]
  (go-loop [col col
            out []]
    (if (seq col)
      (recur (rest col)
        (conj out (<! (f (first col)))))
      out)))
```

Does the standard core.async API have anything like it?

Comment: Channels can be created to apply a transducer to each input -  https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/chan